# nohup not ignoring SIGHUP

Tags: python, linux, chef-infra

I am trying to run a `python` script with `chef`, and the script will exit when `chef` exits because of `SIGHUP`. I am using `nohup` but it still gets the signal. Any ideas how I can get this script to run in the background?

```
nohup python simple-setup.py --dbpath /media/ephemeral0/mongo-data/ -n 2 --name dev --arbiters 1 --mongo_path /usr/bin/ > /media/ephemeral0/log/set.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: How do you know it's getting `SIGHUP`, and not `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL`?

Answer (score 0):

I got round a problem like this by putting the command in a shell script, with an & on the end and then nohupping the shell script. If it helps.